Running a process elevated as a different user
I have a simple powershell script which accepts credentials from the user and executes an exe elevated impersonated as that user.
# Function to run an executable with elevated privileges on a different user
function Run-ElevatedExeOnUser {
    
    $credentials = Get-Credential

    $command = {
        Start-Process -FilePath '"C:\Windows\notepad.exe"' -Verb RunAs
    }

    # Start a new PowerShell process with the credentials and command
    Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList "-NoProfile", "-Command", $command

}

Run-ElevatedExeOnUser

This script works as expected on my development environment, however on one of other environments, I get the following error.
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory name is invalid.
At C:\test\testscript.ps1:17 char:5
+     Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -ArgumentLi ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

I have verified that the other user is a part of the administrators group. Any suggestions as to why this could be happening?
One funny thing here, if I try execute the exe by Shift+Right Click and use the Run as different user option, the exe launches correctly.
What am I missing here?

Does C:\Windows\notepad.exe exist on the other environment? See also Get-Command -Name notepad.

Yes, for that case this script cannot start notepad as well.

If the Windows-provided notepad.exe is to be used, Join-Path -Path $Env:SystemRoot -ChildPath 'system32' -AdditionalChildPath 'notepad.exe'. If the first notepad executable found should be used, (Get-Command -Name notepad)[0].Source.

Let me add some more context, the environment where it fails has 2 users, user1 and user2. Both of them have identical permissions they are a part of administrators group. This script works fine with user1 and with user2 we get the error.

I doubt there is some issue with the path, there is some issue with permissions or access privileges which I am not able to figure out.

I tried this on my home desktop machine, and can confirm it works here.

Are you part of the administration group?  Try start PS by right click on shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Yes, both of the accounts user1 and user2 are a part of Administrators group.
